# Probability Question

Tags: probability

Each day that i arrive the platform on the underground station on my way back home, there is probability $0.177$ that i have to wait more than $3$ minutes for a train to arrive.

What is the probability that out of $21$ days going home by the underground I have to wait more than $3$ minutes for a train to arrive on no more than $3$ occasions?

I tired to let the x is more than $3$ mins and x will no happen more than 3 times.
$P(x\leq 3)= P(x=0) + P(x=1) + P(x=2) + P(x=3) $ 
but I am not sure how to calculate $P(x=0) , P(x=1) , P(x=2) ,P(x=3) $ 
Please give me some advices, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=0.177$ be the probability that you have to wait more than $3$ minutes for the train in any day.

Let $x$ be the number of occasions that you have to wait more than $3$ minutes for the train.

Then:

\begin{align}
P(x=0) &=  p^0(1-p)^{21} \\[2ex]
P(x=1) &= C_{21}^1 p^1(1-p)^{20} \\[2ex]
P(x=2) &=  C_{21}^2p^2(1-p)^{19} \\[2ex]
P(x=3) &= C_{21}^3 p^3(1-p)^{18} 
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
P(x\leq 3) &= P(x=0) + P(x=1) + P(x=2) + P(x=3) \\[2ex]
 \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This is a binomial distribution with $p=0.177$ and $n=21$.
$P(X=k) = B(k,n,p) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$,
where $k=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: i find out that P(x=0) = 0.016726 , P(x=1) = 0.075542 , P(x=2) = 0.162466, P(x=3) = 0.22129 and total is P(x<=3) = 0.476027, but the correct answer is 0.8608. May i ask that which part am i wrong?